# How can I test void methods?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd

I have some void methods and I need to test them, but I'm not sure about how to do it. I just know how to test methods that return something, using Assert.
Someone knows how to do it? Do you guys know some links with exercices in this style?

Comment: If the methods don't do anything that you can observe externally, what useful work are they doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can test two things:

- State changes after void method call (state-based testing)
- Interaction with dependencies during void method call (interaction testing)

First approach is simple (NUnit sample):

```
var sut = new Sut();
sut.Excercise(foo);
Assert.That(sut.State, Is.EqualTo(expectedState)); // verify sut state
```

Second approach requires [mocks](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html) (Moq sample):

```
var dependencyMock = new Mock<IDependency>();
dependencyMock.Setup(d => d.Something(bar)); // setup interaction
var sut = new Sut(dependencyMock.Object);
sut.Excercise(foo);
dependencyMock.VerifyAll(); // verify sut interacted with dependency
```

Well, you also can test if appropriate exceptions are thrown.